# Accent-insensitive search with redisearch

Tags: caching, search, stackexchange.redis, redisearch

Is it possible to do accent-insensitive search with redisearch?
I need the same functionality as SqlServer Collations provides.

e.g. There is a string in index *Atsargų likučiai pagal sandėlius.* It should be found by query string *likučiai* as well as *likuciai*.

Simple and dirty solution would be to store multiple versions of text - real and normalized, normalize all queries, search normalized versions and return real versions as result. But with millions of documents this solution would consume significant amount of memory. Is there a clean way to accomplish this?

Comment: Did you consider fuzzy matching? https://oss.redislabs.com/redisearch/Query_Syntax.html#fuzzy_matching

Comment: @GuyKorland    Yes, but there is some words that differs in single letter but have a totally different meaning. I need exact search, only accent-insensitive. Posibility to use pipe like *liku(č|c)iai* would be invaluable. Thanks for your help!

Comment: https://github.com/RediSearch/RediSearch/issues/718

Answer (score 3):

I was able to find your document by combining both `PHONETIC "dm:fr"` in the schema definition and fuzzy search.

1. Create new schema with the `PHONETIC "dm:fr" option`

```sh
FT.CREATE test_phonetic SCHEMA title TEXT PHONETIC "dm:fr"
```

2. Add document:

```sh
FT.ADD test_phonetic doc_1 0.5 FIELDS title "Atsargų likučiai pagal sandėlius"
```

3. Search using fuzzy search:

```sh
FT.SEARCH test_phonetic "@title:%likučiai%" NOCONTENT WITHSCORES
# returns doc_1 succesfully
FT.SEARCH test_phonetic "@title:%likuciai%" NOCONTENT WITHSCORES
# returns doc_1 succesfully too
```